# Multiple calls to https://northeurope0-completenessp.svc.ms/api/collection

Tags: sharepoint-online

Multiple post calls to https://northeurope0-completenessp.svc.ms/api/collection showing below error:

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://northeurope0-completenessp.svc.ms/api/collection' from origin 'https://mp2018devops.sharepoint.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

How can I resolve it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too.
It's a call to a Microsoft service.
Others dev already open a ticket to Microsoft, I suggest following [this](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4469) thread and wait for a resolution or open a new ticket.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that thread too. This problem started about a week ago.